# Mysql Full Text search When column1=value1 and Column2=value2

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to search a book table with **`Full Text`** where 
 `publisher` `->` `example` and `author` `->` `test`... **OR** 
`publisher` `->` `example` and `auhtor` `->` `test` and `bookname` `->` `another`...

I tried this query:

```
    $this->_query  = "SELECT " . $targetCol . " FROM " . $this->_dbName . "." . $this->_tableName . " WHERE ";
    $this->_query .= "MATCH(publisher) AGAINST('" . $pub . "') AND ";
    $this->_query .= "MATCH(author) AGAINST('" . $aut . "') ";
```

But there's not right result with this.

And I searched in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and found something like this :

```
    $this->_query  = "SELECT " . $targetCol . " FROM " . $this->_dbName . "." . $this->_tableName . " WHERE ";
    $this->_query .= "MATCH(publisher, author) AGAINST('" . $pub . "', '" . $aut . "')";
```

But this one hasn't right result too. It seems these queries focus on first column `publishre in my case`

Would you tell me why? Or Is my query right with my goal?

***`Thanks in advance`***

Comment: What is the output and what should it be? Did you set a full-text index?

Comment: yes, I did.. It should find a book from pulisher `a` and author `john` first in the result, but it shows this book in middle of the result array...

Comment: adjust your question so people know where the trouble is. Right now it is not clear whether the query results in wrong entries, or right entries but wrong order, or something completely different.